# Leaflet Omnivore says CSV file "not well formed"

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm playing with the "Marker Radius" example from Mapbox (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/marker-radius-search/) because I am looking to see how it works and whether I can use it to filter a large data set so that it only shows markers within the screen bounds and then only at higher zoom levels (to avoid showing too many markers).

So far I've taken the example, and all I've done is to replace the example marker set with my own CSV file (which is in the same folder as the example).

Yet when I load it into FF, the console informs me that the CSV file is "not well formed" at Line 1, Character 11 - which is the first comma.

```
"ATCOCode","NaptanCode","PlateCode","CleardownCode",...
```

(and yes, eventually there are Latitude and Longitude columns, but that isn't where it is failing) So what is not well formed about this? It opens in every other CSV-reading application that I have!

Comment: You should try running your CSV through [csv2geojson](https://github.com/mapbox/csv2geojson) - that's how leaflet-omnivore does the conversion under the hood. That should help you narrow your problem down.

Comment: D'oh! It would help if I remembered that "Latitude" != "latitude".